# How to refer current UL LI on a sortable function

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using class to make `<ul>` sortable. Now, I need to get the `<li>`'s `data-cube` values in current `<ul>`.

Currently I'm using '#sortable2 li' but I would like to use something like  `($(this) + ' li')` but Is not working.

```
$("ul.droptrue").sortable({
   connectWith: "ul",
   receive: function (event, ui) {
      var sum = 0;
      var listItems = $("#sortable2 li");
      listItems.each(function (idx, li) {
      var product = $(li);
      sum += product.data("cube");
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to create a jsFiddle sample to illustrate the whole problem?

Comment: Did the answer help, or are you looking for something else..?

Comment: I logged out from my laptop. I'll check it out tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `<li>`'s of receiver `<ul>` inside receive callback like

```
$(this).find("li");
```

or

```
$(this).children("li");
```